# I don't know all the available colors i can use as a back ground color in my program

Tags: c#, background-color

What are all the options available as background color in my program in vs code?
I've already used darkGreen,darkYellow and darkRed, if i use one of these colors, it will not show perfectly. my program is an internal terminal program.

Comment: have a look at ANSI Escape Codes

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH, i know all of the colors available right now, thank u